# Passing Braintree nonce to ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, braintree, braintree-rails

i am currently using braintree hosted fields, to embed the credit cards into my app. i am looking at how i pass the payment nonce from the view to the controller. the javascript i have seems to be triggering the braintree api and returning a nonce to my alert but i just need to now push this through to the controller to execute the final piece of the code

within the controller create method i have

```
def create
    result = Braintree::PaymentMethod.create(
        :customer_id => current_user.customer_cim_id,
        :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client,
        :cardholder_name => "#{current_user.first_name} #{current_user.last_name}",
        :options => {
            :make_default => true,
            :fail_on_duplicate_payment_method => true
        }
    )
```

new view

```
- title t('.title')
= form_for(@payment_method, :url => myaccount_payment_methods_path(@payment_method), :html => {:id => 'cardForm'}) do |f|
  = render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}
/ Load Hosted Fields component.
%script{:src => '//js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.0.0-beta.10/js/hosted-fields.min.js'}
```

form view

```
.mdl-grid
  .panel
    %header.panel__header
      %h1 Card Payment
    .panel__content
      .textfield--float-label
        %label.hosted-field--label{:for => "card-number"}
          %i.material-icons credit_card
          Card Number
        #card-number.hosted-field
      .textfield--float-label
        %label.hosted-field--label{:for => "expiration-date"}
          %i.material-icons date_range
          Expiration Date
        #expiration-date.hosted-field
      .textfield--float-label
        %label.hosted-field--label{:for => "cvv"}
          %i.material-icons lock
          CVV
        #cvv.hosted-field
    %footer.panel__footer
      = f.submit class: 'pay-button', id: 'button-pay', disabled: true
```

application.js

```
var form = document.querySelector('#cardForm');
var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

braintree.client.create({
    authorization: 'sandbox_92dswc7q_mbmb637xwpzgxbrd'
}, function (err, clientInstance) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    // Create input fields and add text styles
    braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: clientInstance,
        styles: {
            'input': {
                'color': '#282c37',
                'font-size': '16px',
                'transition': 'color 0.1s',
                'line-height': '3'
            },
            // Style the text of an invalid input
            'input.invalid': {
                'color': '#E53A40'
            },
            // placeholder styles need to be individually adjusted
            '::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
                'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
            },
            ':-moz-placeholder': {
                'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
            },
            '::-moz-placeholder': {
                'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
            },
            ':-ms-input-placeholder ': {
                'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
            }

        },
        // Add information for individual fields
        fields: {
            number: {
                selector: '#card-number',
                placeholder: '1111 1111 1111 1111'
            },
            cvv: {
                selector: '#cvv',
                placeholder: '123'
            },
            expirationDate: {
                selector: '#expiration-date',
                placeholder: '10 / 2019'
            }
        }
    }, function (err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('validityChange', function (event) {
            // Check if all fields are valid, then show submit button
            var formValid = Object.keys(event.fields).every(function (key) {
                return event.fields[key].isValid;
            });

            if (formValid) {
                $('.pay-button').prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $('.pay-button').prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('empty', function (event) {
            $('header').removeClass('header-slide');
            $('#card-image').removeClass();
            $(form).removeClass();
        });

        hostedFieldsInstance.on('cardTypeChange', function (event) {
            // Change card bg depending on card type
            if (event.cards.length === 1) {
                $(form).removeClass().addClass(event.cards[0].type);
                $('#card-image').removeClass().addClass(event.cards[0].type);
                $('header').addClass('header-slide');

                // Change the CVV length for AmericanExpress cards
                if (event.cards[0].code.size === 4) {
                    hostedFieldsInstance.setPlaceholder('cvv', '1234');
                }
            } else {
                hostedFieldsInstance.setPlaceholder('cvv', '123');
            }
        });

        submit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (err, payload) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }

                // This is where you would submit payload.nonce to your server
                alert('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
                // If this was a real integration, this is where you would
                // send the nonce to your server.
                console.log('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);
            });
        }, false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Right after your `alert` line in application.js, you will want to send a request to your server that contains the payment method nonce. For example you can do this with Ajax:

`$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: your_payment_url,
 data: {"payment_method_nonce":payload.nonce}
 });`

Then within your Ruby on Rails controller, you can call [`Transaction.sale`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby#payment_methods) using the payment method nonce in the request to complete the transaction.
For more information on hosted fields, please check out this [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/hosted-fields).

Edit on Vault question:

If you're using Vault, you can charge users without needing a payment nonce each time. After creating the customer (either through the control panel or through [`Customer.create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/create/ruby), you can retrieve a payment_method_token directly through the [`payment_methods`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby#payment_methods) attribute of the Customer object. To charge the user later, retrieve their payment_method_token on your server and call `Transaction.sale`, passing in the `payment_method_token`.

```
result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :amount => "your_amount",
  :payment_method_token => "payment_method_token"
)
```

Comment: how does this work if we are storing the customers in the vault, as we will be required to get a new nonce every time they want to transact wont we?

Comment: Added a response to your question to my answer.